# Azure ML - How to retrain a model (classic web service)

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I followed this guide to retrain a model (Guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-retrain-a-classic-web-service)

Still there are some questions left. So before retraining a model, do I have to upload the new dataset into my  blob container storage ? If yes how do I do that via http ?

Maybe is it possible to send the new dataset via the PATCH-call in the http body?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

In general this is done automatically by the Retrain Web Service endpoint.
You can refer to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/retrain-models-programmatically) for details.

The page makes reference to the example code that is provided through the Retrain Web Service Dashboard - on the Batch Execution endpoint page: 
[image: batch endpoint]

The example code shows how to upload a new CSV file in Azure Blob Storage, retrain the model and evaluate the results. The Retrain process saves the output files into the Blob Storage account and returns back the information that you need.